# Scrapy Splash results in 504

Tags: python, web-scraping, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to scrape one spesific hotel's page for rates for the comming 28 days. I suspect I'm being blocked, but I'm not quite sure.

I get some results, but not all. I've even tried with various user agents, a download_delay of 30, httpcahce enabled etc.

This is my lua-script

```
    function main(splash, args)
      splash.private_mode_enabled = false
      splash.js_enabled = true
      splash.images_enabled = false
      assert(splash:go(args.url))       
      function wait_for(splash, condition)
        while not condition() do
            splash:wait(20.0)
      end
      end

      wait_for(splash, function()
        return splash:evaljs("document.querySelector('ul.availability-table-revamp') != null")
      end)

      assert(splash:wait(30.0))
      splash:set_viewport_full()
      return {
        html = splash:html(),
      }
    end
```

The page I'm crawling is [here][1].

How do I know for sure it's the page blocking me? There's no policy on the hotels pages - but there are (of course) on the engine's main page ...

I do of course have more code to show, but my guess is that the only thing that can remedy this is the lua. But if you want to see more the complete code is [here](https://codeshare.io/aV4NJ6) :-)

Sure hope you're smarter than me (I guess I allready know the answer to that though).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes web block the user `ip`, try using different `proxy servers`, as it is accessible through my system.

Comment: Hm. I realized that this project maybe did not need splash - as long as the delay time was long enough. So I turned off splash alltogether - and then all pages was scraped perfectly. I find that a little strange. So what could be wrong with my Splash installation/script?